# How to extract only ID photo from CV with pdfimages

Tags: python, image, pdf, extract, pypdf

Hi I tried to use pdfimages to extract ID images from my pdf resume files. However for some files they return also the icon, table lines, border images which are totally irrelevant.
Is there anyway I can limit it to only extract person photo? I am thinking if we can define a certain size constraints on the output?

Answer (score 1):

You need a way of differentiating images found in the PDF in order to extract the ones of interest.

I believe you have the options of considering:

1. Image characteristics such as Width, Height, Bits Per Component, ColorSpace
2. Metadata information about the image (e.g. a XMP tag of interest)
3. Facial recognition of the person in the photo or Form recognition of the structure of the ID itself.
4. Extracting all of the images and then use some image processing code to analyze the images to identify the ones of interest.

I think 2) may be the most reliable method if the author of the PDF included such information with the photo IDs.  3) may be difficult to implement and get a reliable result from consistently.  1) will only work if that is a reliable means of identifying such photo IDs for your PDF documents.

Then you could key off of that information using your extraction tool (if it lets you do that). Otherwise you would need to write your own extraction tool using a PDF library.

Comment: yes, for simplicity I am thinking of (1) but not sure what will be the suitable command ?